# Filling table in angular js using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am able to fill the contents row-by-row. However, I was wondering how would we fill a table with two columns. I want it to be filled columnwise without repeating contents. Basically, it should return a table with two rows and two columns.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
​
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
​
<h1 ng-repeat="x in records">
​
<table align=center>
    <tr>
        <td>{{x}}</td>
        <td>{{x}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</h1>
​
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "Ernst Handel",
  ]
});
</script>
​
</body>
</html>
​
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, at this moment, you are repeating the table element. So you're creating 5 tables, each with one row and two columns. Can you be a little bit clearer with the column-wise part?

Comment: You need to rearrange your data in array to map to your table so that you can use ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS the data are manipulated mostly in JSON and collected as Array data structure.

Get your data from API or service call and convert the data into appropiate array of objects, then the data can be easily assigned to the table column and the record values are assigned to each row of the table using the "ng-repeat" in AngularJS.

In the below code you can see the "ng-repeat" and "x in records" is used as the loop for iterating through records of data values and assign to table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
​
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
​
<h1 ng-repeat="x in records">
​
<table align=center>
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.location}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</h1>
​
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {"name":"Alfreds Futterkiste", "location":"avenue1"},
    {"Berglunds snabbköp", "location":"avenue2"},
    {"name":"Centro comercial Moctezuma", "location":"avenue3"},
    {"name":"Ernst Handel", "location":"avenue4"},
  ]
</script>
​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know how to extract json details. I want to have two json objects side-by-side as shown in description. I appreciate your efforts though.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
​
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
​
<h1 ng-repeat="x in records" ng-if="$even">
​
<table align=center>
    <tr>

        <td>{{x}}</td>
        <td>{{records[$index+1]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</h1>
​
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "Ernst Handel",
  ]
});
</script>
​
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $scope is not taking, change your $scope like js array of object. And Give ng-repeat in correct place. Change your code like below.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js "></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.records = [{name:"Alfreds Futterkiste", location:"avenue1"},{name:"Berglunds snabbköp", location:"avenue2"},{name:"Centro comercial Moctezuma", location:"avenue3"},{name:"Ernst Handel", location:"avenue4"}];
$scope.records1 = [{name:"Centro comercial Moctezuma", location:"avenue1"},{name:"Ernst Handel", location:"avenue2"},{name:"Berglunds snabbköp", location:"avenue3"},{name:"Alfreds Futterkiste", location:"avenue4"}];
}]);
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<table align=center>

            <tr>
              <th>Object one</th>
              <th>Object two</th>            
            </tr>
       
    <tr ng-repeat="x1 in records">    
       <td>{{x1.name}}</td>       
       <td>{{records1[$index].name}}</td>
    </tr>
 
              
</table>
<br>

Your code result:-

<h3 ng-repeat="x in records">
<table align=center>
<tr>
              <th>Country</th>
              <th>Languages</th>              
            </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.location}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
​$scope.records = [
    {name:"Alfreds Futterkiste", location:"avenue1"},
    {name:"Berglunds snabbköp", location:"avenue2"},
    {name:"Centro comercial Moctezuma", location:"avenue3"},
    {name:"Ernst Handel", location:"avenue4"},
  ];

<table align=center>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
        <td>{{x}}</td>
        <td>{{x}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know how to extract json details. I want to have two json objects side-by-side as shown in description. I appreciate your efforts though

Comment: Oh you want two object side by side? now see my updated answer.